# Blockfrost API and cexplorer.io about an asset does not match

Tags: blockfrost, asset

1. When I use Blockfrost to query all the address holders of a token named NMKR,

```
curl  -s -H "Project_id: $BLOCKFROST_PROJECT_ID" https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/assets/5dac8536653edc12f6f5e1045d8164b9f59998d3bdc300fc928434894e4d4b52/address
```

the query returns 100 addresses, with the top holders as follows:
[image]

2. But when I use https://cexplorer.io/asset/asset1lgultx63fukjlhsncmwp235pcnh4fh988phh7f/owner#data

then the top addresses are

```
top_addrs = [
    "addr1vywkezkwgf8e5wprf4nhm266rww8vq2papxpqgns3qrpwcg7vmd7g",
    "addr1qy7wtzzttymfst2umscr6m9xxscfttk0256z85qexf0v8hzx0a8wukmahzq0vn2nqrhgeym0ue2wnufv8nr9ucljtn6s9vtk4h",
    "addr1qy4uaynggpakhe26lgc0vymmdgddrk3uhvgdddlfs8vt4846ghwzul6wjv2r6lkz3pgapen49jmtmls00sn36aacc3csdf0zu6",
    "addr1qyvm697fy60ulksyhjzyz7tmqjt3h8u6s99u7vcqzacfq6z3eekl4qcr5k69u4h02j2wau7js8zgcmp0h5nql3jrdy9qvy4e8t",
    "addr1q98qjgkvv6ul6p5tlxvq9zxklnj87y0lf4s0lta4km4s0scktx0qwk39jnq9a3krt20xa07fgkpf23q4wl3sqcgmrwps79n8u9",    
]
```

These addresses are not included in the 100 addresses above, the amount are also different.
Can you please explain why?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Blockfrost doesn't return the results ordered by quantity (but by time, [see here](https://docs.blockfrost.io/#tag/Cardano-Assets/paths/%7E1assets%7E1%7Basset%7D%7E1addresses/get)), so you'd have to page through the results to see more than those 100 addresses and find the ones you're looking for. When you find them, they will eventually have the same quantities.

For example, you'll find your top address from cexplorer here on page 2:

https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/assets/5dac8536653edc12f6f5e1045d8164b9f59998d3bdc300fc928434894e4d4b52/addresses?count=100&order=desc&page=2

[image]

Comment: I see, thank you very much.